# non-generic Java interface with single generic method with type parameters only on the left side

Tags: java, generics

I recently came upon an instance of the following pattern:

```
public interface IFooFactory {
    <K> Foo<K> create();
}
```

See [here](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/) for a concrete example. I don't see what a client programmer is supposed to do in the implementation of **create** other than instantiate **Foo** with a formal type parameter of **Object** or with no formal type parameter at all. I also don't see what's the benefit or type constraint that the framework designer tried to express by defining the interface **IFooFactory** in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider `Collections.emptyList()`. The list object returned is always the same: since the list is empty and immutable, there is nothing the caller can do with the object returned in order to make it show different behaviour depending on the concrete type substituted for the type parameter. So, a single implementation (with raw types) suffices:

```
public static <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return THEEMPTYLIST;
}

public static final List THEEMPTYLIST = new List() {
    public int size() { return 0; }
    ...
};
```

The `emptyList` method makes this more convenient for the caller, though, since it enables type inference:

```
List<String> noStrings = Collections.EMPTY;  // Gives compiler warning due to use of raw types
List<String> noStrings2 = Collections.emptyList(); // No compiler warning, type parameter inferred.
```

Answer (score 5):

The benefit is for the user of the method, not the implementer. [`Collections.emptyList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29) is a good example of a beneficial use of this pattern. It allows you to declare an empty list like this:

```
List<String> myEmptyList = Collections.emptyList();
```

Had the method returned a raw `List`, `List<Object>`, or `List<?>`, using the method in this way would require a cast.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see what a client programmer is supposed to do in the
>   implementation of create other than instantiate Foo with a formal type
>   parameter of Object or with no formal type parameter at all.

Umm... It's very easy...

```
<K> Foo<K> create() {
    return new Foo<K>();
}
```

Comment: The "return new Foo<K>()" in the body of the create() method, at least in Java 7 where I tried it, seems to be 100% equivalent to "return new Foo()". In both cases you can assign the returned value to an pointer of type Foo<K> or just raw Foo. It could be the late hour in my timezone but I don't see what's the value of <K> in your constructor invocation.

Comment: @MenelaosPerdikeas: Raw types are bad. In Java 7, it might be possible to write it as `new Foo<>()`.